# Adding a measure which finds the next row value for every row (similar to SQL Lead window function)

Tags: powerbi, window-functions

will be very grateful if you could share your experience and advice on the following problem in Power BI:

**3 Tables given in the data model:**

- calendar dimension table
- fact table on sessions
- fact table on spending

  `| CW | Total cost  | Sessions  | Expected Column 1 | Expected Column 2 |
  +----+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
  |  1 |        1200 |        50 |                   |                   |
  |  2 |        1500 |        60 |              1200 |                50 |
  |  3 |        1700 |        48 |              1500 |                60 |
  |  4 |        1150 |        36 |              1700 |                48 |
  |  5 |         900 |        29 |              1150 |                36 |
  +----+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+`

CW column indicates the calendar week and it is from calendar table. Sessions and Total cost are from sessions and spending tables respectively. Data is aggregated and visualized on calendar week level.

**Problem:** I need to create measures to derive Expected column 1 and expected column 2 based on total cost and sessions columns. Basically getting next values for each row similar to lead window function.

I have checked power BI community and there are several ideas (for example here https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-Query-to-Find-Next-Value/td-p/833896).

**But these solution assume all columns are from the same table**, however in the above described case 
all 3 columns are from different tables.

Will the be possible to get expected columns 1 and 2 and how? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is a there a relationship between the dimension and the fact tables?

Comment: @balaji thanks for reply. I found the way.